# whonix black screen after adding new repositories

Tags: debian, virtualbox, kde, whonix

am running whonix inside virtual machine.

Last time I have added debian testing and unstable repositories, than installed firejail from testing, made apt-get update and also apt-get upgrade, and got black screen after reboot.

I saw this picture when tried to log in using console:
[image]

File /etc/ld.so.preload was empty, I removed it, errors left screen but black screen still here.

I don't know how to fix it.

If I am pressing Host+F1, then logging and do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I will see very weird picture:
[image]

last kernel log in attachment

Comment: kernel log https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6nZP.png

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please edit your question by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`  (a text format is better than an image)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and affability dear, I appreciate your efforts and help. Just a min I will try to do that. Text format is problem because clipboard not works (GUI not works, only console), but I will try to find workaround. Thanks.

Comment: first command - file not found, second https://pastebin.com/1qshE5d7

Comment: Please add the output `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ `

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/whonix.list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following source:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/user.list
```

Use the command `history` to identify the installed package from `unstable`(eg: `firejail`) then remove it through `apt-get remove firejail`. also remove the `apparmor` package which cause a problem.

then run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 
apt-get -f install
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! not works :( here is result of history output: https://pastebin.com/Hjv63E4P I tried to remove firejail as you said in instruction, no changes, still here black screen after reboot

Comment: `nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/my_preferences` keep only the stable and set the pin to 1001 `Pin-Priority: 1001` then run `apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: do I need to remove pins numbers for unstable and testing?

Comment: Yes , it is not recommended to use a mixed package from stable , testing and Sid , your system became unstable (or bricked)

Comment: I have made changes as you said, then rebooted, and black screen still here

Comment: remove `firetools` , `apparmor` , `libqt5gui5` and `firejail` then run `whonix_repository --enable --repository stable-proposed-updates`  and `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I only now noticed you edited your answered, removed also apparmor, sent other commands, result same - black screen, also commands of update and upgrade had no any effect - skipped fast as if nothing to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64728/discussion-between-gad3r-and-valueerror).